# how do I loop a click action(refresh) until a specific string is found?

Tags: ruby, loops, watir

I am writing a watir script where I need to loop a click action untill a text is found. Please let me know how to do this.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
require 'watir'

b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto('http://www.example.com')
until b.text.include? "example"
  b.refresh
end
```

But watir and watir-webdriver have methods to handle dynamic page elements.  This [link](http://watirwebdriver.com/waiting/) has examples on waiting with watir-webdriver.